# Can redefined function have different signatures in C++?

Tags: inheritance, polymorphism

Is it possible in C++ that redefined function have different signatures?

Answer (score 0):

Overriding a function or method requires a signature match.  You can, however, create a function overload with a different signature, and call the original function from it.